# Tomcat in Eclipse giving java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException- Cannot recover key error

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, ssl, https

I am trying to configure support for SSL(HTTPS) in Tomcat for my REST Api. I am using Eclipse Mars on my Mac OS X Yosemite.
I edited the Server.xml file of the Tomcat, to enable SSL. I had provided the path to my keystore file in it.

Following are my connection related settings in my **server.xml**:

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="9701"/>

<Connector port="9701" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
maxThreads="200" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
clientAuth="false" keystoreFile="/Users/xyz/.keystore" keystorePass="changeit" keyPass="password" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

Now when I start Tomcat from Eclipse, I get the following error:

```
Jan 23, 2016 7:34:05 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-9701"]
java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
    at sun.security.provider.KeyProtector.recover(KeyProtector.java:328)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:146)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
    at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineGetKey(KeyStoreDelegator.java:96)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
    at java.security.KeyStore.getKey(KeyStore.java:1023)
    at sun.security.ssl.SunX509KeyManagerImpl.<init>(SunX509KeyManagerImpl.java:133)
    at sun.security.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$SunX509.engineInit(KeyManagerFactoryImpl.java:70)
    at javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory.init(KeyManagerFactory.java:256)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeyManagers(JSSESocketFactory.java:608)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeyManagers(JSSESocketFactory.java:537)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:495)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:650)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:434)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:978)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:821)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:642)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:667)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:427)
```

Why I am getting this error and how to remove this error?
And do I need to make any changes in the **Web.xml** of my REST Api so that I can run my api over **HTTPS** only!
Any help would be very appreciated.

Also, I ran Tomcat outside with the same settings and it successfully ran. Though I admit I am fairly new to these things, and so I might be making some small error.

P.S.: I searched a lot over the web and on stackoverflow. But I couldn't find the exact solution to my problem. I hope this question isn't duplicated and even if it happens so, please point out to it in the comments immediately, so that I can delete my question and solve my issue.
Thanks.

Comment: Don't you need a `keyAlias` in your Connector config?

Comment: Hi @Baderous: so you mean I should add another attribute in the Connection settings.
Like I should add **keyAlias="tomcat"** because I generated the keystore file using the following command: $JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA.

Comment: Yes you could try that, but be sure that your keystore contains the private key associated with that alias. That command was used to create the private key, not to store it in the keystore: http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-using-keytool-genkey-private-key-keystore

Comment: @Baderous I figured it out. Both the passwords need to be same. Mentioning the keyAlias is optional.
I generated another .keystore file where in I kept both passwords same, replaced the old one and it worked. Tomcat successfully ran.

Comment: Yes, `keyAlias` is optional, although recommended: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html The passwords don't need to be the same: `keystorePass` is used for accessing the keystore; `keyPass` is used to access the key/certificate inside the keystore. Maybe you had more than one key in your keystore and you were using the wrong `keyPass` or were using the right one but with the behaviour described in the docs when not using a `keyAlias`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the above issue by regenerating another **.keystore** file where in I kept both the "key" and "keystore" passwords same. I replaced the old keystore file with the new one and it worked.

The keystore protects each private key with its individual password(*key password*), and also protects the entire keystore with another password(which is the *keystore password*). We can have both the passwords same as well.

Providing the same password for both fields enabled me to access my REST Api over SSL(HTTPS) on localhost.

I added the following code to the web.xml file to allow the Api to be accessed over HTTPS only:

```
  <security-constraint>
            <web-resource-collection>
                <web-resource-name>clientinfo</web-resource-name>
                <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            </web-resource-collection>
            <user-data-constraint>
                <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
            </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```